# Minima of the function $\ f(x) =\frac{150\times 1.15^x}{x}$

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let f(x) be the function

$$f(x) = \frac{150\times 1.15^x}{x}$$

How can I find the minimum value of that function in the Natural Numbers Domain?

If the derivative of a function is the equation of a tangent line and the max/min of a function is at the slope 0 of the tangent line, will it work on this function to derive and set the f'(x) = 0? If yes, how to derive this function? Also, if yes, will the max/min be the same? Like, $| max | = min$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "will the max/min be the same?" The answer here is no, as you can see from the plot in my answer, and in general the answer will be no, unless the function of interest is constant (at the points where you sample it)

Comment: THe max/min be the same was just a product of my curiosity. By drawing the graph in the Real Numbers group, you can see that the positive and the negative plot are very much alike.

Comment: Edit: Now that I re-checked, I was wrong, the graph does not look alike like 1/x. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to find the minimum of

$$f(x) = \frac{1.15^x}{x}$$

Clearly because you have $x$ in the exponent on the numerator and a polynomial in $x$ on the denominator, $f(x)$ is going to start increasing very quickly for fairly small $x$. So the easiest thing to do is just to calculate the values of $f(x)$ and find the minimum of the values before $f(x)$ starts increasing.

You can see from this plot that this occurs at $x=7$.

[image]

As to taking the derivative, yes you could do that, and find the stationary point at $x=x_0\approx7$ and look at the points either side $x_0-1$ and $x_0+1$ to see which one was smaller.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1.15^x}{x} &= \frac{\log(1.15)1.15^x}{x} -\frac{1.15^x}{x^2}\;\;\;\text{then solve for LHS = 0}\\
0 &= \log(1.15)x - 1\\
x &= \frac1{\log(1.15)}\\
&\approx 7.155
\end{align}$$

But you'd probably want to at least sketch the graph anyway.

Comment: I did draw the graph twice, but the problem is that I'm trying to define a function that gives the amount of time to wait given the equipment that is being used to produce a package. With that, I can tell how much should be invest in the factory to give maximum profit and there are 43 different production equipment each one with a different rate of production. Your answer helps me compute all of them without sketching 43 graphs. Ty.